# Does File Exist? ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

Here is a simple example from W3 Schools:

```
dim fs

strFilePath = "http://lanswinweb1/assembly/scrollingimages/images/" & Session("Num") & ".jpg"
'strFilePath = "P:\Assembly\Team Performance Boards\LDT Scrolling Monitor\" & Session("Num") & ".jpg"
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fs.FileExists(strFilePath) then
  Session("Num") = Session("Num") + 1
  response.write("File: " & strFilePath & " exists!")
else
  response.write("File: " & strFilePath & " does not exist!")
end if
set fs=nothing
```

This is giving me:

[image]

Yet when I go to that link in the web address, it works:
[image]

So, what is it that I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: does a url ever work for fs.FileExists? I'd be pretty surprised if it did

Comment: You should give the link to the article you are referring to so that we can see what it actually says.

Comment: @AndrewMorton https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_fileexists.asp

Comment: @ConradFrix Do you feel smarter now? Your basically just saying, this wont work.  Thats why I am here. lol

Comment: @KyleVbcrlfRickaby Since the sample from w3schools uses a local file path [and the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265024(v=vs.60).aspx) don't make it clear I was wondering if you had a reason to believe that any url would work. Perhaps you should try working with `MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest` instead to check for existence over a url with a vba object

Comment: @ConradFrix  strFilePath = " C:\inetpub\wwwroot\welcome.png" does the exact same thing

Comment: @KyleVbcrlfRickaby A filename is not the same as a URL. The way you said that code was from the source suggests that the source was the problem, not your understanding of it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I get that, but why would C:\inetpub\wwwroot\welcome.png do the same thing? Tell me it doesnt exsist then when I put it in the browser I see the image?

Comment: If you wanted to be really smart you could have used a relative path with `Server.MapPath()` to take a relative URL and map it to a physical path.

Comment: @Lankymart now we are talking! I want to try a few different things with this in mind, thanks

Comment: @KyleVbcrlfRickaby it depends on where `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` maps to, by default it's the Default Website in IIS.

Comment: @KyleVbcrlfRickaby You need to be careful when testing in a browser on the same machine as the web server that you are going through the web server - i.e. the URL in the browser address bar starts with "http".

Comment: @Lankymart Ok that makes sense too. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it shouldn't matter if they physically have a file in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` as long as they check `FileExist()` using that physical path it should work. Ideally they should try something like `Server.MapPath(".")` to see where the relative path is physically mapped.

Comment: @Lankymart Your suggestion works! Thank you for the help, just incase you didnt get my alert from the answer! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to specify file path in VBscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979895/whats-the-correct-way-to-specify-file-path-in-vbscript)

Comment: @Lankymart What I was implying is that testing for a file on the development machine in a browser using the file:/// protocol is no assurance that the file will be available through a web server. It was a reply to *why would C:\inetpub\wwwroot\welcome.png do the same thing? Tell me it doesnt exsist then when I put it in the browser I see the image?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Lankymart for the help!

```
strFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") & "\images\1.jpg"
```

Solves it!